# Is there any inbuilt functionality to handle Windows security authentication popup on browser using UFT tool?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

[image]

I am trying to automate web portal, Everytime when the IE navigates to that web site, it asks for user name and password. It is windows security popup.
In selenium this can be handled by putting username and password before URL something like http://username:password@www.xyz.com. 
I am looking for solution like same in UFT. I am using uft 14.51.

I tried to identify the objects on that popup to enter the user name and password but all are objects are getting added in repository as class window and name as Windows Security. None of the objects are getting identified uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify the username and password in the URL in selenium then you should be able to do the same in UFT.

In any case you should check out UFT's [recovery scenarios](https://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial-29.html) this allows you to perform predefined steps whenever the test encounters and specific error.

Answer (score 0):

IE no longer supports user names and passwords in Web site addresses (HTTP or HTTPS URLs):

> Internet Explorer versions 3.0 to 6.0 support the following syntax for
> HTTP or HTTPS URLs: http(s)://username:password@server/resource.ext
>
> Versions of Windows Internet Explorer that were released starting with
> the release of security update 832894 do not support handling user
> names and passwords in HTTP and HTTP with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
> or HTTPS URLs.

For more information please check this website: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-sit

Try using UIAutomation Add-in:

1. [Open Object Spy Window from toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUGQ.png)
2. [Change Default mode to UIAutomation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfmLx.png)
3. [Activate UIAutomation and hover to the elements you want to identify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phv2K.png)

If you don't have UIAutomation option, see this reference on installing UFT add-ins:
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/z_Sxn_AddinWorkingW.htm#mt-item-1